# How to programmatically exit Apple Watch app and return to watch face?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

When a Push Notification is received on an Apple Watch, pressing the "dismiss" button dismisses the notification **and returns to the watch face screen**.

Within my Apple Watch app, I would like to implement a similar experience to a notification. That is, tapping an icon or selecting a "dismiss" menu item would close or background the app and return the user to the watch face.

This behavior would allow the user to quickly select a new option and go back to the watch face in a single action, without fiddling with the digital crown.

Is it possible, from within an app, to programmatically cause the watch to return to the watch face?

On iPhones, the iOS Human Interface Guidelines [prohibit applications from closing programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739178/does-apple-disallow-the-use-of-a-close-button-on-ios-ipad), as "people tend to interpret this as a crash."

However, the user experience of the watch seems much more oriented around liberally and regularly returning to the watch face. Is it possible to quit or background an app programmatically and return to the watch face, without the user touching the digital crown?

Comment: Did you tries this  exit(0)?

Comment: Did you find a solution other than exit(0) ?

Comment: On iOS you can call UIApplication.shared "suspend" method.
UIApplication.shared.perform(Selector("suspend"))

I am sure there is a way for WatchOS to achieve that but still looking for it...